# How can I change the location in a map using javascript and google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to change the center of a map using an each loop for going to different places, however when I execute the code the map does not show all locations instead the map show the first and last location, I will be grateful if you can help me with this problem.

This is the code:

```js
    var a = new google.maps.LatLng(8.8013, -74.72538);
    var b = new google.maps.LatLng(1.0619, -73.2558);
    var c = new google.maps.LatLng(12.5872, -81.7025);
    var d = new google.maps.LatLng(3.2719, -73.0877);

    var locations = new Array(a, b, c, d);
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(5.0619, -70.2558),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    function initialize() {
        goToLocations(locations);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);   

    function goToLocations(locations) {
        $.each(locations, function (index, location) {
            goToLocation(location);
        });
    }

    function goToLocation(location) {
      // here I can not see all locations 
        window.setTimeout(map.setCenter(location), 5000);        
    }
```

```html
<html>  

  <body>
    
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript">       </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    
    <h1>Map that go to different locations </h1>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width: 500px; height: 380px"></div>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `function` is working fine and it is actually showing all the cities you have on your `array`. However, we are not able to see it. The `function` is exectuted so fast that we are only able to see the first and the last one.

Try to put a `Timeout` inside the `$.each` function and it will work:

```
$.each(locations, function (index, location) {
   window.setTimeout(function(){  
      goToLocation(location);
   }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried to put a `timeout` inside the `$.each` and the problem persist